# show only divs having its index inside an array

Tags: javascript, jquery

Want to show only divs having its index inside an array
In this case - `a`-`c`-`e` - should be visible after the button click

```js
$('button').on('click', function(){
    $('.dbtn').hide();
    let arr = $(this).attr('data-btn').split(',');
    $.each(arr, function(i, val){ 
        $('.dbtn')[val].show();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='dbtn'>a</div>
<div class='dbtn'>b</div>
<div class='dbtn'>c</div>
<div class='dbtn'>d</div>
<div class='dbtn'>e</div>

<button data-btn='0,2,4'>CLICK</button>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that using jQuery method on Vanilla JS object.

`$(...)[val]` returns javascript object which does not have `.show` method.

You can either use `.style.display='block'` or append some class to hide it or put that object inside jQuery function `$()`

```js
$('button').on('click', function(){
    $('.dbtn').hide();
    let arr = $(this).attr('data-btn').split(',');
    $.each(arr, function(i, val){ 
        $($('.dbtn')[val]).show();
        // or
        // $('.dbtn').eq(val).show();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='dbtn'>a</div>
<div class='dbtn'>b</div>
<div class='dbtn'>c</div>
<div class='dbtn'>d</div>
<div class='dbtn'>e</div>

<button data-btn='0,2,4'>CLICK</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

adding to harry's answer if you want to use javascript you can use it like this

```html
<body>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='dbtn'>a</div>
<div class='dbtn'>b</div>
<div class='dbtn'>c</div>
<div class='dbtn'>d</div>
<div class='dbtn'>e</div>

<button data-btn='0,2,4'>CLICK</button>

<script>
  
  $('button').on('click', function(){
    $('.dbtn').hide();
    let arr = $(this).attr('data-btn').split(',');
    $.each(arr, function(i, val){ 
        document.getElementsByClassName("dbtn")[val].style.display='block'
    });
});
</script>

</body>
```

Comment: jquery/js mash ups are really silly. Alteast provide a full non-jquery example.